# Electro-thermal simulation

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, iteration

I'm working on an electro-thermal simulation with variable parameters.
Model require the calculation of all the electrical and thermal quantities at each time step, between a starting and ending time. Parameters change at each time step according to instantaneous electrical or thermal quantities values.
Current implementation is based on a big for loop over a time array with very big size (e.g. start = 0s, end = 50s, step = 200 ns).

In order to speed up the simulation, I'd like to understand if there is a way to optimize such types of codes. Maybe avoiding the `for` loop?

In this example is evaluated resistor current *I* knowing the resistor voltage *V*.

*I = V/R*

R depends on actual current and temperature and it's read from look-up table.

| ID | R_T1 | R_12 | T |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1.42 | 1.92 | 50 |
| 100 | 2.72 | 3.22 | 100 |
| 200 | 4.02 | 4.52 |  |
| 300 | 5.32 | 5.82 |  |
| 400 | 6.62 | 7.12 |  |
| 500 | 7.92 | 8.42 |  |
| 600 | 9.22 | 9.72 |  |
| 700 | 10.52 | 11.02 |  |

Temperature is supposed linear with time.

**Functions**

1. lookup returns linear interpolation with extended range
2. `R_LUT` returns the resistance value which result from look-up table with inputs `I` and `T` at each time step.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
from bisect import bisect_left
from numba import jit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib notebook
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [10, 5]

def lookup(x, xs, ys):
    
#     if x <= xs[0]: return ys[0]
#     if x >= xs[-1]: return ys[1]
    
    if x <= xs[0]:
        k = (x - xs[0])/(xs[1] - xs[0])
        y = k*(ys[1]-ys[0]) + ys[0]
        return y
        
    if x >= xs[-1]:
        k = (x - xs[-2])/(xs[-1] - xs[-2])
        y = k*(ys[-1]-ys[-2]) + ys[-2]
        return y
    
    if x in xs:
        index = int(np.where(xs == x)[0]),
        return ys[index]
    
    i = bisect_left(xs, x)
    k = (x - xs[i-1])/(xs[i] - xs[i-1])
    y = k*(ys[i]-ys[i-1]) + ys[i-1]
    
    return y


def R_LUT(I,T,curr,R_matrix,temp,R_min,R_max):
            
    if len(temp) == 1:
        R = lookup(I,curr,R_matrix)

    if len(temp) > 1:
        index_1 = bisect_left(temp, T) - 1
        
        if index_1 == -1:
            index_1 = 0
            
        if index_1 == len(temp) - 1:
            index_1 = len(temp) - 2
            
        index_2 = index_1 + 1
        R_1 = lookup(I,curr,R_matrix[index_1])
        R_2 = lookup(I,curr,R_matrix[index_2])
        R = lookup(T,np.array([temp[index_1],temp[index_2]]),np.array([R_1, R_2]))
        
#     if R < R_min:
#         R = R_min
#     if R > R_max:
#         R = R_max
        
    return R
```

**Parameters**

```
I_table = np.array([0,
100,
200,
300,
400,
500,
600,
700,
])

R_T1_table = np.array([1.42,
2.72,
4.02,
5.32,
6.62,
7.92,
9.22,
10.52,
])

R_T2_table = np.array([1.92,
3.22,
4.52,
5.82,
7.12,
8.42,
9.72,
11.02,
])


R_matrix = [R_T1_table, R_T2_table]
T_table = np.array([50, 100])

R_min = 1
R_max = 12
V_amp = 5000
T_start = 50
starting_time = 0 #[s]
ending_time = 100*pow(10,-3) #[s]
step_time = 100*pow(10,-6) #[s]
```

**Code**

```
time = np.arange(starting_time, ending_time, step_time) #[s]
time = np.round(time,10) #[s]
T = np.zeros(len(time))
I = np.zeros(len(time))
R = np.zeros(len(time))
V = V_amp*np.sin(2*np.pi*50*time)
T[0] = T_start

for i in range(0,len(time)):
    
    I[i] = V[i]/R[i]
    
    if i > 0:
        T[i] = T[i-1] + .05
        
    if i < len(time) - 1:
        R[i+1] = R_LUT(abs(I[i]),T[i],I_table,R_matrix,T_table,R_min,R_max)
```

**Plots**

```
plt.figure()
plt.plot(time,V)
plt.title('voltage')
plt.xlabel('time [s]')
plt.ylabel('[V]')
plt.xlim(0, ending_time)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(time,I)
plt.title('current')
plt.xlabel('time [s]')
plt.ylabel('[A]')
plt.xlim(0, ending_time)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(time,T)
plt.title('temperature')
plt.xlabel('time [s]')
plt.ylabel('[°C]')
plt.xlim(0, ending_time)
    
plt.figure()
plt.plot(time,R)
plt.title('resistance')
plt.xlabel('time [s]')
plt.ylabel('[ohm]')
plt.xlim(0, ending_time)
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I [changed the title](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/287636/revisions#rev-body-ec5c84d6-5c05-41c3-89ec-d24765132db3) so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._". Feel free to [edit] and give it a different title if there is something more appropriate.

Comment: This submission is about performance (and includes no [profiling](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html#module-cProfile) measurements). Well, really it's about performance **and** accuracy. But you've not offered any description of your desired error bars. Many ODE / PDE solvers will use variable timesteps, e.g. sample at 5 kHz when a pair of bodies in an N-body simulation closely approach each other, and sample at 1 Hz when they're far away. You haven't explained the relevant dynamics of your System Under Test, nor your error tolerance. Please be explicit about error magnitudes.

Comment: In the table, is T temperature or time? Why are there only 2 values there? Please add some explanations to the values in the table and link them to what you're trying to achieve. Right now, I'm guessing it's "given starting state [I, R, V, Temp, Time] produce the next state [I, R, V, Temp, Time]", and this is done by the procedures you detailed - Time and Temp are linear, R is looked up based on I and Temp while amplitude of V is known and the actual value follows a sinusoidal wave.

Comment: Hello @low-altitude, you got the algorithm meaning. T is temperature and for each value of temperature there is one curve I - resistance (e.g. for T-table = 50 the corresponding I-R curve is R_T1_table). At each R_LUT call, resistance output is calculated with 3 Linear interpolations, 2 with respect to current and one with respect to temperature. However, the original algorithm (which I can't post) is way more complex, with lot of electrical and thermal quantities evaluated with differential equations and numeric integration. There are several parameters evaluated with lut at each step